# Sort one array according to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to sort the `array1` according to the order of the values in `array2`.

An example will explain better.

`const array1 = [7, 2, 6, 3, 4, 1]; const array2 = [1, 2, 9]`
and I expect to have

`const array3 = [1, 2, 7, 6, 3, 4]`.

==========

Furthermore, let's say we have got `const object1 = {key5: value5, key3: value3, key4: value4, key1: value1, key2: value2}; const array2 = ["key1", "key2", "key3"]` .

how can I get the following object `object3 = {key1: value1, key2: value2, key3: value3, key5: value5, key4: value4};`

Could anyone let me know the clean way to achieve this ?

Comment: This seems to be a pretty unique problem so I'm not sure this would built in, but you might be able to create a modified insertion/selection sort for this.

Comment: `array2.filter(x => array1.includes(x)).concat(array1.filter(x => !array2.includes(x)))` This can be a solution if you are not looking for the most efficient one. Comment if you need an optimised solution. I can try :)

Comment: @Akhil Yep, that seems to be a good solution. I have edited the description a bit because I found that sorting inside the array and object are quite diffierent,

Comment: Please only one question per question. You currently have two - how to sort an array and how to sort an object. These are distinct things.

Comment: @VLAZ Right, but only one question is allowed in any 90 minutes, so I edited the description. Apologies if it made you angry :-)

Comment: @AndriiNaidenko I wrote an answer. But can you explain why object key sorting is needed :-)

Comment: @AndriiNaidenko I'm not angry at all. I'm explaining the policy to try help you avoid your question be closed. You can always wait to post a second question. Do note that sorting is a very common topic, so it might even be a duplicate.

Comment: @Akhil Because I draw the area chart from this object and we already determined the orders.

Comment: @AndriiNaidenko Okay check if my answer helps.

Comment: @Akhil Yep, marked as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need an object with sorted keys? Seems not so useful and cant understand the usecase. But here is a possible solution.

```js
const object1 = {key5: 5, key3: 3, key4: 4, key1: 1, key2: 2};
const array2 = ["key1", "key2", "key3"]

const array1 = Object.keys(object1)
const resultObj = array2
.filter(x => array1.includes(x))
.concat(array1.filter(x => !array2.includes(x)))
.reduce((acc, key) => {
 acc[key] = object1[key];
 return acc;
}, {});

console.log(resultObj)
```